# masked redirect from subdirectory to subdomain in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dns, cloudflare

i was wondering if its possible to do a masked redirection from a subdirectory to a subdomain (or other website)

```
example.com/blog
```

to

```
blog.example.com
```

so for example if users go to example.com/blog/page1 they are actually going to blog.example.com/page1

i am using cloudflare + azure to host my asp .net mvc application

what i have found is ways to do this with a normal redirect, but i was wondering if its possible to do it in a masked way?

looking at rewrites im trying the following:

```
<rule name="blog" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^/blog" negate="true" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

this doesnt seem to work for some reason. i just get a 404 not found error on /blog now.

Comment: The IIS Rewrite Module can do this.https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: @VDWWD could u look at my example?

Comment: I think it should be `url="^blog$"`